# Where can I license sample libraries for a virtual iOS instrument?

Tags: sampling

I'm making a virtual instrument for mobile devices. Where can I license a sample library from for this purpose?

For example I would need individual audio files for individual piano notes. The license would would need to permit my mobile app to play these samples when my users press keys on a on-screen piano keyboard.

What's the ballpark price for a simple library with only one velocity layer?

Answer (score 1):

Try the mildon piano

http://www.mildonstudios.com/soundware_acoustic_piano_extended.html

The extended license for $109 sound appropriate for your needs.

Comment: Are you affiliated with Mildon?

Comment: you asked and answered with this. but you make it sound like someone else answered it

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the free [Yamaha Grand Piano](http://zenvoid.org/audio/) samples? They are [CC-Atribution 3.0 licensed](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/). [More samples](http://wiki.laptop.org/go/Sound_samples) from the [OLPC](http://wiki.laptop.org/go/The_OLPC_Wiki) project.